# Ruby setter method syntax method=(value) - Comparison to Java

Tags: java, ruby, methods, setter

Hello dear stackoverflowers :)

I came from Java and have one doubt about the syntax of getters (if it's really just a syntax issue).

In java you would have a setter like

```
private void setName(value) {
    variableName = value;
}
```

who would take value as an argument and change the instance variable inside it.

In ruby, when I explicitly define a setter (due to constraint reasons), I need to use set_name=(value) or if I use the syntax set_name(value) would be the same? In other words, the = in the end of the method name does anything else or it's just syntax (like ! and ?).

Like this:

```
def set_name=(value)
    @name = value
end
```

Or this:

```
def set_name(value)
    @name = value
end
```

Thanks in advance for the attention.

Alex

Comment: This seems like a fairly basic question - are you using any books or websites to learn Ruby?

Comment: Yes, I'm using teamtreehouse and also looking at the internet to see the concepts. But this one after searching almost all the web, was still not clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing `=` in the method name identifies the method as a setter/mutator method. When you say this in Ruby:

```
o.p = v
```

You're really saying:

```
o.send(:p=, v)
```

so `o.p = v` is just a fancy way of calling the `p=` method in `o`. That's why things like this:

```
's'.pancakes = 11
```

gives you a `NoMethodError` exception that complains about `'s'` not having a `pancakes=` method: Strings don't (unfortunately) have `pancakes=` methods.

In your case, you wouldn't use `set_name` at all, you'd have a `name=` method:

```
def name=(value)
  @name = value
end
```

and possibly a `name` method as an accessor/getter:

```
def name
  @name
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The most idiomatic approach in Ruby is to do

```
def name=(value)
  @name = value
end
```

or better yet,

```
attr_writer :name
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use set_name=(value) or if I use the syntax set_name(value)
>   would be the same?

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name1=(str)
    @name = str
  end

  def name2(str)
    @name = str
  end
end

d = Dog.new("Rover")
puts d.name  #=>Rover
d.name1 = "Ruthie"
puts d.name  #=>Ruthie
d.name2("John")
puts d.name  #=>John
d.name2 = "Roger"

--output:--
1.rb:23:in `<main>': undefined method `name2=' for #<Dog:0x00000100907030 @name="John"> (NoMethodError)
```

For setters, the name of the method includes the '=' sign.  But ruby also allows you to use syntactic sugar with method names that end in '=':

```
obj.setter_name = value
```

is equivalent to:

```
obj.setter_name=(value)
```