# Why can I change the method name when I call a setter method from a class?

Tags: ruby, class

I'm looking at this example:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name, :age   #creates getter method's age & name     

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def age=(a)               # creates setter method for age
    @age = a
  end
end
mike = Person.new('Mike') 
mike.age = 20               # calling setter method
mike.age                    # calling getter method, returns 20
```

And I'm trying to understand why "mike.age = 20" is the equivalent to saying "mike.age=(20)".

I understand that we don't have to use parentheses in Ruby for the arguments that we're passing into the method. So I know why "mike.age = 20" is the same as "mike.age= 20". However, I'm having trouble understanding why we can put a space after "age". Isn't the equals sign a part of the method name? For example, I know I can't say:

```
def is_even?(n)
   n.even?
end

p is_even ? 3
```

Because the question mark is a part of my method name, I know that I can't separate it with a space. So why am I able to separate "age" and the equals sign with a space in the setter method in the first example?

Comment: @Glyoko Oh! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: It's syntactic sugar that exists for certain methods

Comment: The simple answer is: because the Ruby Language Specification says so. Why can you use a `.` to call a method but not a `:`? Why can you use `"` to delimit a string and not `,`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the StackOverflow link where 'mu is too short' answers this:
[Ruby setter method syntax method=(value) - Comparison to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004582/ruby-setter-method-syntax-method-value-comparison-to-java)

When you add two numbers, for example

```
4 + 4
```

This is what's going on

```
4.send(:+, 4)
```

The send method just invokes a method. The first argument is the method you want to call  passed in as a symbol `:+` and the second argument is the argument you want to pass into the method `4`

In your case

```
mike.age = 20
```

is actually this

```
mike.send(:age=, 20)
```

Here, we are calling the `age=` method and passing in `20` as the argument to `age=`

Heres the link to the Ruby docs about the send method https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Object.html#method-i-send